# How to get a background in php with a file explorer picture

Tags: php, html, background

Hi I'm trying to get a background in php for a project that I'm working on but I don't seem to get what wrong with the one I have now?

```
<?php
$profpic = "C:\Users\Adam\Pictures\phpproject\Bjoia Oct10 15-09.png";


?>

<html>
<head>
<?php include_once('C:\Users\Adam\Pictures\phpproject\Bjoia Oct10 15- 
09.png'); ?>
<title>Title</title>

</head>



<body>



</body>





</html>
```

Im supposed to to get a background with a picture that i have

but instead the page just crashes any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your PHP is running on a server (even if you're running on localhost). It cannot access your filesystem, rather it can only access files on the server. You need to reference files relative to where your PHP `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` is, like `../Bjoia Oct10 15-09.png` or similar.

You also can't [`include()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) an image in the `<head>` (this throws a syntax error); you need to output the path to the image inside of an `<img src="">` in the body. This *can* be done with `echo`, assuming the string representation of the path to the file is stored inside of a PHP variable:

```
<body>
<?php $image_path = "../Bjoia Oct10 15-09.png`"; ?>
<img src = '<?php echo $image_path; ?>' />
</body>
```

If your path isn't stored in a variable, you're essentially just writing HTML; no need for PHP whatsoever. The above will transpile to the following HTML, which you can write directly if you so desire:

```
<body>
<img src = '../Bjoia Oct10 15-09.png' />
</body>
```